# Migrate Django model to unique_together constraint

Tags: django, migration, unique-constraint, django-south

I have a model with three fields

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a    = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b    = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c    = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

I want to enforce a unique constraint between these fields, and found django's `unique_together`, which seems to be the solution. However, I already have an existing database, and there are many duplicates. I know that since `unique_together` works at the database level, I need to unique-ify the rows, and then try a migration.

Is there a good way to go about removing duplicates (where a duplicate has the same (A,B,C)) so that I can run migration to get the `unique_together` contstraint?

Comment: do you have any other fields on your model (that may affect the choice of which duplicate to keep)?

Comment: i have a created_at time which would probably be the best indicator

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are happy to choose one of the duplicates arbitrarily, I think the following might do the trick. Perhaps not the most efficient but simple enough and I guess you only need to run this once. Please verify this all works yourself on some test data in case I've done something silly, since you are about to delete a bunch of data.

First we find groups of objects which form duplicates. For each group, (arbitrarily) pick a "master" that we are going to keep. Our chosen method is to pick the one with lowest `pk`

```
from django.db.models import Min, Count

master_pks = MyModel.objects.values('A', 'B', 'C'
    ).annotate(Min('pk'), count=Count('pk')
    ).filter(count__gt=1
    ).values_list('pk__min', flat=True)
```

we then loop over each master, and delete all its duplicates

```
masters = MyModel.objects.in_bulk( list(master_pks) )

for master in masters.values():
    MyModel.objects.filter(a=master.a, b=master.b, c=master.c
        ).exclude(pk=master.pk).del_ACCIDENT_PREVENTION_ete()
```

Comment: Can we do something similar in migration file itself which would avoid having to run extra script?

Comment: What is `.del_ACCIDENT_PREVENTION_elte()`?

Comment: `delete` with the phrase `ACCIDENT_PREVENTION` added in the middle to prevent people accidentally deleting stuff by copy/pasting the code without reading it

Comment: @chhantyal Just put it in a migration file. Look at the Django docs for data migrations. I just did one, simple as can be.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a slightly improved answer that will delete everything in a single query, instead of looping and deleting for each duplicate group. This will be much faster if you have a lot of records.

```
non_dupe_pks = list(
    Model.objects.values('A', 'B', 'C')
    .annotate(Min('pk'), count=Count('pk'))
    .order_by()
    .values_list('pk__min', flat=True)
)

dupes = Model.objects.exclude(pk__in=non_dupe_pks)
dupes.delete()
```

It's important to add `order_by()` in the first query otherwise the default ordering in the model might mess up with the aggregation.

You can comment out the last line and use `dupes.count()` to check if the query is working as expected.